# After Struts2 jar file upgrade, application intermittently throws InvocationTargetException and unknown parent package null

Tags: java, struts2

Upgraded Apache Struts jar file from struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar to struts2-core-2.5.18.jar and then application intermittently throws exception.

**The main part of the exception**

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException -
Class: 
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4
File: ContainerBuilder.java

Method: create
Line: 161 - 
com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerBuilder.java:161:-1
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.setContainer(DefaultUnknownHandlerManager.java:50)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:405)

Caused by: Unknown parent package: null - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.codebehind.CodebehindUnknownHandler.(CodebehindUnknownHandler.java:73)

Comment: It appears you are using the codebehind plugin which has been deprecated since struts 2.1 https://struts.apache.org/plugins/codebehind/.  Potentially something has been introduced that broke it.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I removed the codebehind plugin jat file and deployed the application. As the problem is intermittent, I need some time to confirm the solution. I will update once I thoroughly test it.